# How to overcome "There is no ini file for the requested language" with babel for Tamil language?

Tags: xetex, babel, tamil

Using the following tex with `xelatex` on Ubuntu:

```tex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{tamil}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package babel Error: There is no ini file for the requested language
(babel)                (). Perhaps you misspelled it or your installation
(babel)                is not complete..
```

How should I install/ configure things properly on my system
to allow xelatex to render Tamil text using the babel package?

---

**Edit:**

An even more concise MWE is the following:

```tex
\usepackage[tamil]{babel}
```

This yields the following:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `tamil'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file tamil.ldf was not found.
```

---

**Edit 2:**

The following shows `texlive-lang-indic - TeX Live: transitional dummy package` ... which does not seem very encouraging. Does texlive, and therefore babel, not support Tamil (and other Indian languages)?

```
$ sudo apt-cache search texlive-lang
debiandoc-sgml - DebianDoc SGML DTD and formatting tools
texlive-lang-african - TeX Live: transitional dummy package
texlive-lang-all - TeX Live: metapackage depending on all TeX Live language packages
texlive-lang-arabic - TeX Live: Arabic
texlive-lang-chinese - TeX Live: Chinese
texlive-lang-cjk - TeX Live: Chinese/Japanese/Korean (base)
texlive-lang-cyrillic - TeX Live: Cyrillic
texlive-lang-czechslovak - TeX Live: Czech/Slovak
texlive-lang-english - TeX Live: US and UK English
texlive-lang-european - TeX Live: Other European languages
texlive-lang-french - TeX Live: French
texlive-lang-german - TeX Live: German
texlive-lang-greek - TeX Live: Greek
texlive-lang-indic - TeX Live: transitional dummy package
texlive-lang-italian - TeX Live: Italian
texlive-lang-japanese - TeX Live: Japanese
texlive-lang-korean - TeX Live: Korean
texlive-lang-other - TeX Live: Other languages
texlive-lang-polish - TeX Live: Polish
texlive-lang-portuguese - TeX Live: Portuguese
texlive-lang-spanish - TeX Live: Spanish
```

---

**Context:**

I have already got Tamil fonts installed (Ubuntu default):

```
$ fc-list | grep tamil
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil-classical/Lohit-Tamil-Classical.ttf: Lohit Tamil Classical:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-tamil/Lohit-Tamil.ttf: Lohit Tamil:style=Regular
```

Also, I have the appropriate texlive package installed:

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-indic
```

My tex file includes the following as well, for context
Note that removing them does not appear to affect the outcome.

```tex
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[tamil]{rm}{Lohit Tamil}
```

Comment: works okay for me. Is you tex system up-to date? And did you install all of babel (the tamil files should be in `tex/generic/babel/locale/ta`)

Comment: how do I check if my tex system is up to date?
and what do you mean by "install all of babel"?

Comment: somewhere in your log-file there will be dates. Look if they look current, for example is something say "2021" (new) . Most importantly naturally is the date of babel.

Comment: hmm, I'm not that advanced - what's the command to install or update babel?

Comment: sorry I'm on windows, and I don't know which system you use on ubuntu.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the file you want is `babel-ta.ini`, and it should be in the Ubuntu package `texlive-latex-base`.

Comment: Running `sudo apt install texlive-latex-base` yields `texlive-latex-base is already the newest version (2017.20180305-1).` ... which does look pretty old. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: Also have this installed: `texlive-latex-extra is already the newest version (2017.20180305-2).`

Comment: Interesting, I do appear to have the file installed: `ls /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/ta/` --> `babel-ta.ini  babel-tamil.tex` ... so if that's not the underlying reason, what's causing the errors?